# Entering data into excel sheet using matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am entering a dynamic data into excel sheet from a textbox. The problem is that it enters letter by letter in every cell.

This is the code I have tried:

```
 >>function bntEnterData_callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)
 >>val1 = get(handles.txt1,'string'));
 >>val2 = get(handles.txt2,'string'));
 >>val3 = get(handles.txt3,'string'));
 >>values = [ val1 val2 val3]
 >>filename= 'try.xls';
 >>sheet= 1;
 >>xkRange= 'A2';
 >>xlswrite(filename,values,sheet,xlRange);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to fix the formatting of your code so that it displays correctly. However, I am not 100% what you are looking for. Can you write more precisely what you are expecting to happen?

Comment: I don't understand *it enters letter by letter in every cell*. Can you show us an example set of values of `val1`, `val2` and `val3`, what you get in the Excel sheet and what you wanted to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `handles.txt*` are edit `uicontrols`, the `'String'` property is going to be a character vector. Concatenating multiple character vectors just creates a longer vector:

```
a = 'foo';
b = 'bar';
values = [a b]
```

Which creates:

```
values =

    'foobar'
```

When not explicitly provided a range of cells to write to, [`xlswrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) will interpret the input single cell (or the default `A1`) as the starting point, and write all elements of the input array using the single cell as the origin. Because `'foobar'` is an array of characters, this gives the expected behavior of:

[image: no]

To fix this, concatenate into a cell array:

```
a = 'foo';
b = 'bar';
values = {a b};

filename= 'try.xls';
sheet= 1;
xlRange= 'A2';
xlswrite(filename,values,sheet,xlRange);
```

[image: yay]